# Как получить запись в WP по значению поля?

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице фильтрации выбираю фильтр записей по "ООО Рога и копыта". В коде фильтрации прописано:

```
function true_filter_function(){
  $post_type = $_POST["post_type"];
   if($_POST['company']){
       echo '0';
   }

if (!isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['company'])) {
      echo '3';   
      $args1 = array(
      'post_type' => $post_type,
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'asc',
      "tax_query" => array(
        array(
          "taxonomy" => 'company_db',
          "field"    => "slug",
          "terms"    => $_POST['company'],
          'operator' => 'IN',
        )
      ),

    );

  }

    echo var_dump($args1);

  $posts = new WP_Query($args1);
    
  if ($posts->have_posts()) 
   {
    echo '5';
    while ($posts->have_posts()) 
      {
        $posts->the_post();
        if ($post_type === 'project') 
              {
                 get_template_part('template-parts/loop-project');
               }
      }
    } 
    else {
          echo '<div class="mess-not-found">Ничего не найдено</div>';
         }
}
```

На странице выходит:

> 03array(5) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "project" ["numberposts"]=> int(-1) ["orderby"]=> string(4) "date" ["order"]=> string(3) "asc" ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "company_db" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(55) "ООО Рога и копыта" } ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" } } }
> Ничего не найдено

Маяки 0 и 3 показывают, что в функции зашли, а также есть значения в "$args1", но маячок **echo '5';** не отработал...

Что не так делаю? Почему не получается фильтровать записи?

UPD:

1. Посмотрел через var_dump() значение:

```
$posts->have_posts()
```

Там **False**

2. Значение **$posts = new WP_Query($args1);** Через var_dump():

> object(WP_Query)#10910 (51) { ["query"]=> array(5) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "project" ["numberposts"]=> int(-1) ["orderby"]=> string(4) "date" ["order"]=> string(3) "asc" ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "company_db" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(55) "ООО Рога и копыта" } ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" } } } ["query_vars"]=> array(68) { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "project" ["numberposts"]=> int(-1) ["orderby"]=> string(4) "date" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "company_db" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(55) "ООО Рога и копыта" } ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" } } ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["lazy_load_term_meta"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(10) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "company_db" ["term"]=> string(55) "ООО Рога и копыта" } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#10913 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "company_db" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(55) "ООО Рога и копыта" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" ["include_children"]=> bool(true) } } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(1) { ["company_db"]=> array(2) { ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(55) "ООО Рога и копыта" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" } } ["primary_table"]=> string(8) "wp_posts" ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" } ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#10912 (9) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL ["meta_table"]=> NULL ["meta_id_column"]=> NULL ["primary_table"]=> NULL ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["clauses":protected]=> array(0) { } ["has_or_relation":protected]=> bool(false) } ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["request"]=> string(444) " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'project' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'))) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10 " ["posts"]=> array(0) { } ["post_count"]=> int(0) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(0) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_archive"]=> bool(true) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(true) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(false) ["is_privacy_policy"]=> bool(false) ["is_404"]=> bool(false) ["is_embed"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(true) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(false) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_favicon"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(true) ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=> string(32) "fbdf29666831e6871b92ef1f0d91b840" ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["allow_query_attachment_by_filename":protected]=> bool(false) ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=> NULL ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "query_vars_hash" [1]=> string(18) "query_vars_changed" } ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "init_query_flags" [1]=> string(15) "parse_tax_query" } }

UPD 2:

Исправил POST отправку. Теперь в фильтрацию уходит в POST:

> { ["post_type"]=> string(7) "project" ["numberposts"]=> int(-1) ["orderby"]=> string(4) "date" ["order"]=> string(3) "asc" ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "company_db" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> NULL ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" } } }

Comment: `"terms" => "ИП Маганов Валерий Николаевич"` - может, тут проблема? В terms по идее должно быть что-то латинскими символами без пробелов. Вы передаёте в запрос кириллическое имя термина, а передаваться должен слаг

Comment: Сорян, там "ООО Рога и копыта" - то, что в запросе. Сейчас просто когда менял  - забыл поменять. Т.е. передовать надо не строку?

Comment: Да это и не важно - передавать надо латинский slug термина, а Вы передаёте кириллическое имя. Видимо, из-за этого запрос и не отрабатывает

Comment: @humster_spb, Я новичок просто в WP. А запрос разве не как в SQL работают тут? Не делают запросы по параметрам? Типа:  "Выбрать для ТАБЛИЦЫ , где поле ИМЯПОЛЯ = "РОГА И КОПЫТА" ?,

Comment: Вы меня не слышите )) У Вас в запросе указан `"field" => "slug"`, соответственно, в terms надо передавать латинский слаг Вашего термина, а не его кириллическое имя "РОГА И КОПЫТА". Вы можете попробовать изменить на  `"field" => "name"`, возможно, это позволить отработать запросу с кириллической строкой.

Comment: @humster_spb, я же говорю, что новичок =). Поменял -  не дало результата..

Comment: Так а в чём проблема slug передать в $_POST, а не имя?

Comment: @humster_spb, Дополнил вопрос. Теперь уходит slug, но все равно не отображаются

Comment: Ну, я вижу в Вашем вардампе `"terms" => NULL`. Значит, не уходит slug (или не приходит)